# add indexing to custom list

Tags: c#

I have the following list:

```
public class MyQueue : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private Node Head { get; set; }
    private Node Tail { get; set; }

    public MyQueue()
    {
        Head = null;
    }

    public void Add(int item)
    {
        Enqueue(item);
    }

    public void Enqueue(int item)
    {
        var newItem = new Node { Data = item };

        if (Head == null)
        {
            Head = newItem;
            Tail = newItem;
            return;
        }

        Node last = Tail;
        last.Next = newItem;
        Tail = newItem;
    }
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        Node current = Head;
        while (current != null)
        {
            yield return current.Data;
            current = current.Next;
        }
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    private class Node
    {
        public int Data;
        public Node Next;
    }
}
```

There are other methods, but they do not matter in this scenario.
I'd like to add indexing to this list.

So I can do something like:

```
var q = new MyQueue() {1, 2};
Console.WriteLine(q[0]); //1
```

What do I need to implement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public int this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        return this.Skip(index).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: q[0] returns the value 2 and not 1 :) otherwise, it is really clever!

Comment: You sure? Works on my machine. For index == 0 Skip(0) does "nothing".

Comment: My bad! I tested the code further down in my test case (which does a lot of other things).

It works perfectly and I like the clever implementation

Answer (score 6):

you need to make a property like this:

```
public int this[int index]
{
    get {
        // code to return value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx). An indexer enables you to access a `class`, `struct` or `interface` as if it were an array. The syntax is as follows:

```
public int this[int index] {
    get {
        // obtain the item that corresponds to this index
        // return the item
    }
    set { 
        // set the value of the item that corresponds to 
        // index to be equal to the implicit parameter named "value"
    }
}
```

Here's an explicit example for your case:

```
public class MyQueue : IEnumerable<int> {
    // ...
    public int this[int index] {
        get {
            if (index < 0 || index > this.Count() - 1) {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
            }
            return this.Skip(index).First();
        }
        set {
            if (index < 0) {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
            }
            Node current = Head;
            int i = 0;
            while (current != null && i < index) {
                current = current.Next; i++;
            }
            if (current == null) {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
            }
            current.Data = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement the `this` operator.

Comment: I could use a little more help :) *nudge nudge*

Comment: Yes, but you can and should show the syntax of the `this` property (like my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Write a [`this` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02%28VS.71%29.aspx), like this: (pun intended)

```
public int this[int index] {
    get {
        return something;
    }

    //Optionally:
    set {
        something = value;
    }
}
```

---

Also, you should probably implement [`IList<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx).  (Note, though, that the `Count` property would require a loop)

Comment: I'd like to know why you think I should IList<int> :)
What are the advantages?

Comment: So that any code that works with `IList<T>` will be able to use your class as well.